# Trying to generate scaffold controller and got an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am trying to generate a controller with scaffold from Entity framework and I got this error : **exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation**

I have already tried everything I searched on google and it does not worked for me.

WebConfig connectionString:

```
 <add name="defaultConnection"
   connectionString="@Data Source=DESKTOP-TJMV4UV\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TesteMVC;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

My model:

```
 [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; } /*ID IS THE PRIMARY KEY*/
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Posts> Posts { get; set; } /*ONE CATEGORY HAS MANY POSTS*/
```

My Context Class:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppContext() : base("name=defaultConnection") { }

        public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Posts> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to get the results of creating a scaffold controller with views automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved, but don't ask me how I did it. In programming sometimes magic happens.**